# Why do I get an error when trying to add kali repositories using katoolin?

Tags: apt, updates, repository, katoolin

Why do I get an error when trying to add kali repositories to ubuntu using katoolin?

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.D2xAqE4gla/gpg.1.sh --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys ED444FF07D8D0BF6
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
```

I am running on Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: I suggest you reconsider using Kali. Kali is not for beginners. The question suggests that you might find the Kali experience frustrating.

Comment: @user535733 Yeah, maybe you are right I guess

Comment: Kali is a security related OS so everything needs to be done by you the user and will not be done automatically. One of those manual things is adding a key for installing. The whole idea of Kali is that you do not depend on others as others can not be trusted so you either know how the system works or you investigate how to do it.